# wpalchemy repeating fields dropdown issue

Tags: theme-development, wpalchemy

I need to allow user to select portfolio items from a dropdown, these selected portfolio items will be displayed on homepage.

I have used wpalchemy class to create repeatable section that contains a dropdown list of all portfolio pages.

Issue is whenever i click on update button, a copy of dropdown is automatically added to repeating list.

```
<?php while($mb->have_fields_and_multi('col1-project')): 
    $mb->the_group_open(); 
    $mb->the_field('portfolio-list1');
    $args = array (
        'name' => $mb->get_the_name(),
        'id' => $mb->get_the_name(),
        'selected' => html_entity_decode($mb->get_the_value()),
        'post_type' => 'portfolio'
    );
    wp_dropdown_pages($args); 
    $mb->the_group_close();
endwhile; ?>
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/alokjain-lucky/6682775

Comment: Have you reported that as bug [on GitHub](https://github.com/farinspace/wpalchemy)? Also there needs to be much more information on that question (or better: on a GitHub issue). Namely your complete setup of the fields, not just your meta fields loop.

Comment: I am not sure if that is a bug in wpalchemy class or an issue in my code, that's why i have not reported this as a bug till now. Also i have only 1 field (selectbox) there are no other fields.

Comment: Why not show a setup (that one can download for e.g. from GitHub Gist) that everybody can read up, download and test?

Comment: Gist added in question.

Comment: Please add the code where you register the fields as well. Such a Gist can only work if one is able to pull it into a local install and febug that for you.

Comment: I have added other files to Gist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to loop through all pages, instead of using `wp_dropdown_pages()` function.

Following is the new code

```
<?php while($mb->have_fields_and_multi('col2-project')): ?>
<?php $mb->the_group_open(); ?>

    <p>
        <span>Select Project</span>
        <?php $mb->the_field('project-id-2'); ?>
        <select name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>">
            <option value="">None</option>
            <?php
                global $thispost;
                $myposts = get_pages('post_type=portfolio&post_status=publish');

                foreach($myposts as $thispost) :
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $thispost->ID; ?>" <?php $mb->the_select_state($thispost->ID);?> ><?php echo get_the_title($thispost->ID); ?></option>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php setup_postdata($thispost);?>
       </select>
    </p>

<?php $mb->the_group_close(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Issue with the previous code was that there was no empty value, so every time a new value was saved when update button was clicked.

Now i have added `<option value="">None</option>` as default value.